# What's up with all that JS frameworks?

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js

I am .NET (do most of my work in ASP.NET WebForms) developer. But I am not limiting myself to that framework only and read and try to learn new stuff from time to time.

Lately I noticed a lot is happening in Javascript world. I'm familiar with jquery/UI and calling web services from client side. But lately I see a lot of new frameworks written in Javascript. I really don't know why so many are created lately. Can anyone enlighten me why is that happening? What are the differences between different frameworks. When should I use/not use them? For example node.js is something totally weird for me. Writing server side code in JS? Writing HTTP servers in JS (or maybe no one really does it?). Creating client side UI on JS only? I really don't get it. Add to this at least 5 templating frameworks and my head is about to explode :)

Comment: fair question, but unfortunately doesn't fit here on SO. BTW what's wrong with node.js? It's nothing weirder than doing it in .NET ;)

Comment: It is weird for someone doing it in .NET :)

Comment: Ive been doing .NET for 4 years now, took me about 6 months to get used to it, but now its like second nature.

Answer (score 3):

[Atwood's law](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/07/the-principle-of-least-power.html):

> Any application that can be written in JavaScript, will eventually be written in JavaScript.

The real story is: nodejs (or v8) allows developers to write *applications* in Javascript that can be executed outside a browser. This makes Javascript as powerful as Python or Ruby. Nodejs was adopted faster than any language in history, because many developers already know Javascript. Suddenly it's possible to write applications in Javascript, so we are in a gold rush of development. Many from the Ruby community (who are early adopters) tried nodejs, so it inherited a culture of sharing libraries under permissive licences.

---

I don't use the client-side/server-side language because it's confusing and a false dichotomy.

Comment: +1 for the law.`Any application that can be written in JavaScript, will eventually be written in JavaScript`

Answer (score 1):

I think all the javascript server side libraries are now coming out because of Google's V8; The highly efficient JS engine that Google made for Chrome. It compiles the JS codes and therefore runs its pretty fast.

It was not too long ago that V8 was released.

It makes it easy to run js without a browser efficiently.

The biggest downside of node.js is probably that a fatal error will crash the entire http daemon. So one visitor can bring the entire site down unless a lot of care has been taken.

I think the biggest advantage of js-server-side like node.js is that you can run the same code on server and on browser. This is particularly useful for form validations, for example.

As compared to PHP, node.js also provides the advantage of being able to make non-blocking calls. In fact with node.js its really hard to make any blocking calls.

I wouldn't call node.js a framework though, I see it more like an essential library for which a framework still has to be made (or does one exist already?).

Linkedin is built on node.js and they seem to be very pleased with it. However their site seems to be quite backward to me.

Answer (score 0):

All the fuss about JS is because of the great UI experience the user can get. Instead of the user waiting for the page to refresh every single time they do something, the results are almost instantaneous. I agree with @Karoly Horvath's comment. JQuery may seem weird at first, but its because of the unknown, it's great to work with once you are used to the syntax. Getting back to the user experience, if your page takes forever to load/reload, the users will rather use another site. Your question is not really fit for Stack Overflow, but im sure you will find some additional answers and opinions in the chat sites available on SO. Good luck.

Comment: But you can create one page apps without node.js. Just use jquery, that's all you need.

Comment: Yes you can, but I don't really know any professional developers that do actually write one page apps :-). And if you do its probably for yourself, so you can define what libraries and tools you want to use